# MongoDB with Expo React Native

Tags: reactjs, database, mongodb, react-native, expo

I have been trying to figure out which database to use with my React Native project (using Expo). I need online capabilities eventually, but would prefer to develop locally. I was initially looking at MongoDB/Realm, but both appear to not support expo. Is this correct? Or is there a way to use MongoDB with React Native and Expo?

Comment: use REST api to work with MongoDB or other databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you can use whatever database you like by connecting to it through a REST API using fetch in your react native project, in case you want to implement offline and realtime capabilities i suggest you take a look to firestore or realtime database